# Error handling OpenFileDialog in VB

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, openfiledialog

I am new to VB, so I appreciate this might seem like a stupid question.

I am using the following code to select a CSV file from the local file system.

```
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\uploads"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True


    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

    End If


        '--TextField Parser is used to read the files 
        Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(openFileDialog1.FileName)
```

How can I make this error gracefully, if a file is not selected.

So in essence display a message saying "No file selected"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: place `Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(openFileDialog1.FileName)` in `If .. End If` Condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim strFileName As String
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\uploads"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        strFiilename = openFileDialog1.FileName
        If strFileName <> "" Then
            'file is selected
        Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(strFiilename)
        Else
            MsgBox("No File Selected")
        End If
    End If
```

i think no need to check for this `strFileName` because in your question you have placed

```
Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(openFileDialog1.FileName)
```

after

```
If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
endif
```

this will leads your error